# JavaScript: Backbone.js fetch json and load it into a collection of models?

Tags: javascript, collections, model, backbone.js, extend

So far i have the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working, and I don't know when the asynchronous fetch is completed:

```
var item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 0,
        an_id: 0,
        strval: null,
        th_id: 0,
        text: null
    },
    url: 'page.php',
    options: {
        success: function(data) {
            alert('s: ' + dump(data));
            // the dump function is my way of dumping objects into a string,
            // use console.log if you want, as I have that disabled
        },
        error: function(x, t, e) {
            alert('e: ' + t + ', ' + e);
        }
    }
});

var coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: item
});

var options = new Options();
Backbone.sync("create", coll, item.options); // 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating c.url) in backbone-min.js
```

**Update**

I have modified the original code to what I have now, and the backend can now tell the difference between New, Update, Save and Delete requests.

I still cannot find out how to populate the collection `coll`.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Generally you'll want to hook a view up to your model and bind your view's render method to events that you model fires. If you're fetching, bind the reset event to your views render as reset will fire once the response returns from the server.

Comment: @kinakuta, I have no idea how to do any of that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Backbone.Collection` is for keeping multiple items - you seem to be trying to have your Collection "inherit" from your model, which isn't the right approach.

> Collections are ordered sets of models. You can bind "change" events
>   to be notified when any model in the collection has been modified,
>   listen for "add" and "remove" events, fetch the collection from the
>   server, and use a full suite of Underscore.js methods.

Comment: As I pointed out, I have only started using this library. Do you have a definitive suggestion on how to store a list models (properly) and listen for change, add and remove events and get a list of the available collection?

Comment: I have updated my code, how can I populate my collection of items?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a success handler to your fetch call. try this:

```
coll.fetch({
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
            console.log(coll.toJSON());
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error")}
    });
```

Comment: The success handler is called, but the `toJSON()` function displays an empty string.

Comment: sounds like your api call isn't configured correctly. I'd ask if you can go into the developer tool in your browser to see what network calls are made, see what your call is returning. 

also a useful tool to test api calls is this: (for chrome)
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&ei=Ge4yT5LwG83LrQfy0fGsDA&usg=AFQjCNFbhSdZTBn3IVB6kaplCJIs613x_Q

Comment: I have updated my code, how can I popualte my collection of items?